# Is it better to do reviews quicky or not to do them at all?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Here "I" is a hypothetical person.

I only do reviews when it shows notifications, I suppose that it is the time when the system needs help. And here are specific examples:

1. If the post is bad, I just hit recommend deletion with "No comment needed", because, well, I am too lazy to choose the option, the post will be gone anyway.
2. If there's an edit which, let's say, improves code formatting, then I just quickly look through it to see if it is really better, but I do not compare code token by token to check if the editor messed something up.
3. Or let's say a suggested edit says that link is broken, so the editor replaces it with another, I read the URL, but do not click on them to see if the old one is really dead and the new one is nice.
4. If the edit says that the editor incorporated some stuff advised in comments into the answer, I look through the edit, but I do not check out what the comments say.

Etc. Most examples are about the suggested edits, but the question is general: should I do reviews without completely studying the subject but just evaluating if the creator of the event did something adequate, or not at all? Of course I skip them if I can't tell the quality of the event at a glance.

Answer (score 21):

If you're not actually going to make sure that the thing that you're reviewing is correct, then no, you shouldn't be reviewing at all.  Reviewing incorrectly is **way** more harmful than not reviewing at all.

Having a suggested edit take a bit longer to be handled is *dramatically* preferential to having improper edits approved because the reviewer wasn't even checking if the edit was appropriate.

Recommending deletion of posts that don't actually meet the criteria for deletion is *way* more problematic than it taking a bit longer for potentially delete-worthy posts to be reviewed.  Additionally, having feedback to the author on why their post is deleted is very important for helping them avoid making the same mistakes in the future.  This is particularly true of non-answers, because people that post them quite often *continue* to post them until they're informed that it's not acceptable behavior.

Comment: I would like to add that in the case of a link-only answer I have seen it being improved after getting the comment from review.